# clear textbox after submit button click in php

Tags: php, html, textbox

i want to clear text box after submit click.

i tried this code:

```
   $("#btn").live('click',function(){
        $(this).parents('productinstallation').find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').val('');
   });
```

but it's not working. is there any another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('productinstallation').find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').val('');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet there is:

Assign a id or class to your input: example: id=tbEmail

Then use this:

```
$("#tbEmail").val("");
```

Or for the full form:

```
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) jQuery method was removed in version 1.9. Depending on which version of jQuery you are using, the `live` method might not work. Try using the `on` method or `click`

```
   $("#btn").on('click',function(){
        $(this).parents('productinstallation').find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').val('');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

try by assigning ids to them.

```
$("#btn").live('click',function(){    
    $(selector).val('');
   });
```